# VB6 excel file not saving

Tags: excel, csv, vb6

Basically, title. I open and make changes to an .csv (I'm fine with a normal excel file if someone can get it to save properly) file (specifically, autofit and bold everything), but when I go and open the file, nothing has changed. Anyone know why? I honestly have no idea what I'm doing :p and the internet doesn't seem to have any information on this.
As a side note, if the .exe crashes while running, and then I open the excel file, it's formatted properly.  Here's the code:

```
Dim spreadsheet As Excel.Application
Set spreadsheet = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
spreadsheet.Workbooks.Open _
    FileName:=exportPath, _
    ReadOnly:=False

Call spreadsheet.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Call spreadsheet.Selection.Columns.AutoFit
spreadsheet.Selection.Font.Bold = True

spreadsheet.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (App.Path & "\" & "THISONE" & gc_AppName & "EXPORT" _
    & Format$(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd/hhmm") & gc_ExportExtension)
MsgBox (spreadsheet.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value)

Call spreadsheet.SaveWorkspace
'Call spreadsheet.ActiveSheet.Save
Call spreadsheet.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Call spreadsheet.ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)
Set spreadsheet = Nothing
```

Comment: Try `spreadsheet.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs App.Path... , FileFormat:=xlNormal` instead of `SaveCopyAs `.

Comment: Excellent - this works. Thanks a bunch!